# Firebase Storage with Flutter didn't get file type

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

I upload image to Fireabse Storage from Flutter project here is my code.

```
return storageRef
          .ref(profileDir)
          .child("${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.png")
          .putFile(profilePhoto)
          .then((taskSnapshot) => taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL());
```

But in firebase Storage, the type is not appear, how can I get to show type.

[image]

Comment: you don't need to set metadata manually. firebase would detect this file type automatically. I had encounter this issue recently and it took me 2 days to found the what caused this issue. First of all, what device you are using to upload the file? android or ios?? try to upload file from iphone to check this issue happened too?  let me know, I would update the information to help you find the solution

Comment: Now, What I trying device is Android, I will try it in iOS and leave a comment after that. Thanks for your effort. Now, I solve this issued by adding settableMetadata to putFile method.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to [set metadata for the file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/file-metadata). Without this, files stored default to `application/octet-stream`. for example:

```
.putFile(profilePhoto, SettableMetadata(contentType: 'image/png'))
```